# Fill a complex Java Object with dummy values

Tags: java, reflection

If A, B, C, D are classes. Suppose a class A is structured as below.

```
    class A{
    private List<B> bList;
    private String name;
    private boolean dude;
    private C c;
    private D d;
    //Getter and Setter Methods
    }
```

B , C and D have some properties like String, boolean etc. say

```
class B{
private String e;
private boolean b;
.....
//Getter and Setter Methods
}
```

Now I want to create an object of A with its property B, C and D not being null but filled with Dummy values say `"abc"` for `String`, `1` for `int` , `false` for `boolean`.

So the aim is to create an object `A` with dummy values. How can this be achieved ?

Comment: I don't know if there is something that does it automagically, but you might want to look for mocking libraries

Comment: Similar question without an accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250505/how-fill-all-fields-in-the-class

Comment: @defaultlocale the only difference is, this question got -3 while the other one got +3. Weird community!

Comment: @Null SO is not deterministic.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose there are many ways.  Most depend on what you're trying to do and details of the overall project, but here are a couple...

I would assume this is for test code, in which case mockito might prove useful (though if it's not for test code... well, I wouldn't use a mocking lib for any sort of production code).

Or, this is much easier in Groovy (which compiles to bytecode and can coexist with Java in a project)... but again, I usually resist the use of Groovy in production code so would recommend this mostly if you're writing test code.